# Kendo UI Dropdown inside iframe - scrollbar is not visible

Tags: iframe, drop-down-menu, scrollbar, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI Dropdown inside a webpage, this page is displayed using an iframe in another page.The list has around 100 items.

I am not able to see the scrollbar for the dropdown list. The whole list is displayed inside the iframe. You can see the snapshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZKQW.png).

Kendo UI Version used : 2012.3.1114

Note : This issue appears in IE9 and Firefox 14. Chrome displays the dropdown as expected. Also, the dropdown works fine when the page is loaded separately in a new window.

Comment: Which version of Kendo UI are you using? Did you check with the latest?

Comment: @OnaBai - i am using the latest version 2012.3.1114.

Comment: That's the latest GPL but there is 2012.3.1315 that has some bugs fixed related with browsers. Can you post some code in JSFiddle reproducing it and I check with the latest?

Comment: @OnaBai The issue is because of the other libraries i am using for this project. I was not able to reproduce this issue when i created a separate page with just Kendo UI. I should have done this before posting here :( thanks a lot for your time! :)